# How to set this mouseover to show even when mouseover morethan 3 sec only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to set this mouseover to show even when mouseover morethan 3 sec only ?

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/YVk6Z/317/

```
$(function() {
    $('#target').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).animate({height: '300px'});
    });


        $('#target').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '100px'});
    });
});
```

When you fast `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` , `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` on `<div id=target></div>` you will see an even loop

How to apply this for, if `mouseenter` lessthan 3 sec even not show

Answer (score 2):

You could always use [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the animation queue:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/YVk6Z/320/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#target').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).stop(true).delay(3000).animate({
            height: '300px'
        });
    });

    $('#target').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            height: '100px'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: how to set 3 sec mouseenter ?

if mouseenter lessthan 3sec , even not process.

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก Change `delay(1000)` to `delay(3000)`?

Comment: `delay()` should come after `stop()`

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก The above / fiddle has been udpated

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก...that seems to be a different question? (albeit related)

Answer (score 1):

With pure css you could do something like this

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YVk6Z/324/)

**The Style:**

```
#target {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: height 300ms 0s ease;/* animate height | in 300ms | with delay= 0s*/
}
#target:hover {
    height: 300px;
    transition: height 300ms 3s ease;/* animate height | in 300ms | with delay= 3s*/
}
```

**The Markup:**

```
<div id=target></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a variable which cancels itself on mouseout and then delay the animation based on `mouseOut` being false:

```
$(function() {
    var mouseOut = true;
    $('#target').mouseenter(function() {
        mouseOut = false;
        var that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!mouseOut){
             that.animate({height: '300px'});
            }
        }, 3000);
    });


        $('#target').mouseleave(function() {
            mouseOut = true;
        $(this).animate({height: '100px'});
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/YVk6Z/321/

Comment: How to set time of mouseenter ?

Comment: Edit where it says `3000` 1 second = `1000` so 3 seconds = `3000`